# C++ std::set or .NET SortedSet equivalent in VB6?

Tags: vba, vb6

I need the representation of std::set in VB6
Example:

```
Dim mySet as VB6Set
mySet.add "item1"
mySet.add "item2"
mySet.add "item3"

If mySet.Find(item2) then
      ....
end if
```

Comment: Have you looked at Collection or Dictionary?

Comment: About the collection - I'm looking it right now. I thought it is something like vector or list.
About the dictionary - it requires 2 parameters. It is possible to use Dictionary as a Set, but it is not a good idea.

Comment: It is not at all clear to me what this question means. Are you doing interop in VB 6 with a C++ application that uses `std::set`? Or are you just asking how you would create a data structure *similar* to `std::set` (i.e., a sorted container) in VB 6?

Comment: Why exactly is a Dictionary "not a good idea"?.  If you only need to use the keys, use `vbNull` for the items. It's more or less a drop-in replacement in the example code from your question.

Comment: I use just the keys in dictionaries all the time. So you have dictionaries, collections, arrays, and you can also access .NET (add a reference to mscorelib) things. ADODB can also be used as a disconnected database of 1 field.

Comment: @Cody Gray - I need an equivalent of std::set in VB6?

Comment: `Scripting.Dictionary` comes closest. Can use `Exists` method instead of `Find` and `mySet.Item("item1") = True` instead of `add` method in the sample snippet.